# How to make href anchors in iframe `srcdoc` actually work

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have some html content that I am loading in an iframe. I'm loading the html content through the `srcdoc` attribute. Unfortunately, when following  anchor tag links inside the iframe it loads the entire page within the iframe, instead of scrolling to the tag with the linked id.

JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/kzLdqjgs/5/

I can get the anchor tags to work using `src="data:text/html,<p>my html</p>"` but I'm curious as to why it doesn't with with srcdoc. Furthermore, the src attribute for some implementations apparently has a limit of 32,768 characters and the content I'm trying to load is over 60k characters in length (though this seems to work fine in Chrome).

Comment: Interesting question.. I don't know well srcdoc attribute so I won't be able to help too much on it... For the length limit, you can always use a Blob and a blobURL https://jsfiddle.net/kzLdqjgs/6/ But weirdly enough, FF doesn't honors the hash link (chrome does and FF should).

Answer (score 8):

I found `href="about:srcdoc#some_id` in iframe srcdoc would work(at least in Chrome, I didn't test it in other browsers).

From Wikipedia:

> `about:srcdoc`: A reserved, though unresolvable, URI defined within HTML5 intended to be the URI navigated to within iframes whose content comes from the srcdoc attribute.

[See the link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme#Standardization)

Comment: Maybe you can quote from wiki what you want him to see. It's better to describe more.

Comment: Your are a life saver! Thankyou! I tested in Chrome 101 and Safari 15.4, and it works in both.

Comment: This is unbelievable. I spent 2 hours trying to find the solution to this problem and actually thought I was losing my mind, because there seems to be no reference to this anywhere else on the internet. Thank you for posting this1 Surely this must be a common problem?

Comment: Thank you. I used this inside Tailwind Play.